# Ssh/Ping Problems in Mac Yosemite through wifi but not ethernet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, ping, osx-yosemite

I am using Mac Yosemite OS to connect to my office servers via ssh. I am not able to connect through any of the Wifi (my apt's wifi or my work place's wifi). However, I am able to do ssh when I am connected via ethernet. I did the following things to solve the problems but I was not successful.

1. Switched off my firewall but I still was not able to get connected.
2. I pinged my server and I got  `Request timeout` status. However, when I pinged or did ssh through my other **Mac (which has Maverick OS)**, I was able to get positive response of my ping message and got connected (in case of any wifi).
3. I did ssh -vvv username@host, I received the following message

   ```
   OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
   debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
   debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
   debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 100: Applying options for *
   debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
   debug1: Connecting to <server name> [<server ip address>] port 22.
   debug1: connect to address <server ip address> port 22: Operation timed out 
   ssh: connect to host <server name> port 22: Operation timed out
   ```
4. I re-installed OpenSSL and still was not able to fix the problem.
5. I got similar problems when I used Cyberduck, Firezilla or VNC but not in case of my other computer which has OS Maverick.

Do you have any ideas or suggestions that I should try ? Thanks!

******Update 1*******

I removed OpenSSL & brew and tried connecting to the server. I did

```
ssh -vvv uname@<server-name>
```

The message says that the connection is established. However, I am not able to move ahead after the following message:

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
```

Here is entire message:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 100: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to <server name> [<ip address>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/snape/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/snape/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/snape/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/snape/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH*
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "dna.nri.bcm.edu" from file "/Users/aayushraman/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /Users/aayushraman/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 127/256
debug2: bits set: 504/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 59:d3:ec:27:16:df:01:04:8a:7a:92:34:3f:91:16:8d
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "dna.nri.bcm.edu" from file "/Users/snape/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /Users/snape/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "10.34.48.30" from file "/Users/snape/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /Users/snape/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '<server name>' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/snape/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 513/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
```

**Also when I tried to do ping, I am able to do it and able to receive the message and not errors !!**

I think I am pretty close to the solution and for sure brew didn't work properly on my mac yosemite.

********Update 2**********

I was able to solve the problem by:

1. removing the brew
2. basically giving the argument for UseDNS as no

   vi /etc/sshd_config 
   UseDNS no
3. service sshd restart by

   unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK

and then do ssh

Comment: what does traceroute host tell you? You say you get a timeout on both imp ping and tcp on port 22. This would suggest there is a connectivity issue. Can you use the internet when only connected to wifi?

Comment: Hi @Paul -- I ran traceroute <server name> and I didn't receive any error message. It ran for 64 hops showing that the packets were received. I have tried using internet both thru wifi and ethernet cable of my apartment. I don't know why am I having connectivity issue on my one Mac with yosemite but other one works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by:

1. removing the brew
2. basically giving the argument for UseDNS as no

   vi /etc/sshd_config
   UseDNS no
3. service sshd restart by

   unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK
4. and then do ssh